# Circular shift top of a Stack by n elements

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to write a method which performs a circular rotation of the top n elements of a stack by k positions.

I can do a circular shift of a one dimensional array by n positions, but I don't know how to do this using a stack.

I'm thinking that maybe a linked list maybe help?

Comment: Questions like this will generally do better if showing current code and explaining why it doesn't work or doesn't correctly solve the problem - also, make sure the title and actual question "agree".

Answer (score 0):

You can use some other stacks to keep track of the top n elements. myStack is your original stack. int n is the amount of elements you want to rotate.

```
public Stack rotateStack(Stack myStack, int n){
 Stack firstNElements = new Stack();
 Stack remainingElements = new Stack();

 for(int i=0; !myStack.isEmpty() && i<n; i++){
  firstNElements.push(myStack.pop());
 }
 while(!myStack.isEmpty()){
  remainingElements.push(myStack.pop());
 }


 Stack newStack = new Stack();
 while(!firstNElements.isEmpty()){
  newStack.push(firstNElements.pop());
 } 

 while(!remainingElements.isEmpty()){
  newStack.push(remainingElements.pop());
 }

 return newStack;
}
```